# Cannot open jupyter notebook - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have only installed python 3.7.8 64-bit on windows 10 today. I did use 3.7.8 32-bit version before but now I have to use 64 bit version due to some package requirement. But after I installed jupyter notebook, I cannot launch it in the command prompt via `jupyter notebook` and it gives this error:

`C:\Users\86133>jupyter kernelspec list`

`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\86133\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\jupyter.exe" kernelspec list': ???????????`

The path of python is `C:\Users\86133\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`

So how do deal with it properly? Appreciate a lot!

```
--------------
I also attach the pip list:
Package             Version
------------------- ---------
altair              4.1.0    
anyio               2.0.2    
aplus               0.11.0   
appdirs             1.4.4    
argon2-cffi         20.1.0   
astor               0.8.1    
astroid             2.4.2
astropy             4.2
async-generator     1.10
attrs               20.3.0
Babel               2.9.0
backcall            0.2.0
base58              2.1.0
beautifulsoup4      4.9.3
bleach              3.2.1
blinker             1.4
boto3               1.16.63
botocore            1.19.63
bqplot              0.12.21
branca              0.4.2
bs4                 0.0.1
cachetools          4.2.1
certifi             2020.12.5
cffi                1.14.4
chardet             4.0.0
click               7.1.2
cloudpickle         1.6.0
colorama            0.4.4
cycler              0.10.0
dask                2020.12.0
decorator           4.4.2
defusedxml          0.6.0
distlib             0.3.1
entrypoints         0.3
enum-compat         0.0.3
filelock            3.0.12
fsspec              0.8.5
future              0.18.2
gevent              20.12.1
greenlet            0.4.17
h5py                2.10.0
idna                2.10
importlib-metadata  3.3.0
ipydatawidgets      4.2.0
ipykernel           5.4.3
ipyleaflet          0.13.6
ipympl              0.6.3
ipython             7.19.0
ipython-genutils    0.2.0
ipyvolume           0.5.2
ipyvue              1.5.0
ipyvuetify          1.6.1
ipywebrtc           0.5.0
ipywidgets          7.6.3
isort               5.7.0
jedi                0.18.0
Jinja2              2.11.2
jmespath            0.10.0
json5               0.9.5
jsonschema          3.2.0
jupyter             1.0.0
jupyter-client      6.1.11
jupyter-console     6.2.0
jupyter-core        4.7.0
jupyter-server      1.2.3
jupyterlab          3.0.6
jupyterlab-pygments 0.1.2
jupyterlab-server   2.1.3
jupyterlab-widgets  1.0.0
kiwisolver          1.3.1
lazy-object-proxy   1.4.3
llvmlite            0.35.0
locket              0.2.0
MarkupSafe          1.1.1
matplotlib          3.3.3
mccabe              0.6.1
mistune             0.8.4
nbclassic           0.2.6
nbclient            0.5.1
nbconvert           6.0.7
nbformat            5.0.8
nest-asyncio        1.4.3
notebook            6.1.6
numba               0.52.0
numpy               1.19.5
packaging           20.8
pandas              1.2.0
pandocfilters       1.4.3
parso               0.8.1
partd               1.1.0
pickleshare         0.7.5
Pillow              8.1.0
pip                 21.0.1
prettytable         2.0.0
progressbar2        3.53.1
prometheus-client   0.9.0
prompt-toolkit      3.0.10
protobuf            3.14.0
psutil              5.8.0
pyarrow             3.0.0
pycparser           2.20
pydeck              0.5.0
pyerfa              1.7.1.1
Pygments            2.7.3
pylint              2.6.0
pyparsing           2.4.7
pyrsistent          0.17.3
python-dateutil     2.8.1
python-utils        2.5.5
pythreejs           2.2.1
pytz                2020.5
pywin32             300
pywinpty            0.5.7
PyYAML              5.3.1
pyzmq               22.0.2
qtconsole           5.0.1
QtPy                1.9.0
requests            2.25.1
s3fs                0.2.2
s3transfer          0.3.4
selenium            3.141.0
Send2Trash          1.5.0
setuptools          52.0.0
Shapely             1.7.1
six                 1.15.0
sniffio             1.2.0
soupsieve           2.1
streamlit           0.62.0
tabulate            0.8.7
terminado           0.9.2
testpath            0.4.4
toml                0.10.2
toolz               0.11.1
tornado             6.1
traitlets           5.0.5
traittypes          0.2.1
typed-ast           1.4.2
typing-extensions   3.7.4.3
tzlocal             2.1
urllib3             1.26.2
vaex                3.0.0
vaex-arrow          0.5.1
vaex-astro          0.7.0
vaex-core           2.0.3
vaex-hdf5           0.6.0
vaex-jupyter        0.5.2
vaex-ml             0.9.0
vaex-server         0.3.1
vaex-viz            0.4.0
validators          0.18.2
virtualenv          20.4.1
watchdog            1.0.2
wcwidth             0.2.5
webencodings        0.5.1
websocket           0.2.1
websocket-client    0.57.0
wheel               0.36.2
widgetsnbextension  3.5.1
wrapt               1.12.1
xarray              0.16.2
zipp                3.4.0
zope.event          4.5.0
zope.interface      5.2.0
```

Comment: do I need to install python 3.7.8 32-bit as well?

Comment: -How many bits does your computer have? Please install and use python that matches the bit of your computer. In addition, have you installed the "python" extension and the "Jupyter" extension?

Comment: @JillCheng I just delete all past python installing files and install 64-bit version again and it works.